# Google Data Studio - Charting discreet values from a "checkboxes" google form question

Tags: looker-studio

I'm building a dashboard with Google Data Studio and my data source is a `Google Sheet`, that has collected information from a Google Form.

On the form, there are some checkbox questions, to which a respondent can "select all that apply". The responses to these types of questions are stored as comma separated values in a single column in the sheet.

This leads to charts and graphs in `Data Studio` that are not as useful as I would want them to be.

For example, consider the question "What kind of fruit do you like?" and the following answers:

```
Form Submission 1) Apples

Form Submission 2) Oranges

Form Submission 3) Apples, Oranges
```

The way a pie chart is drawn currently in Data Studio, I would have three slices...  "Apples", "Oranges" & "Apples, Oranges", with each slice with a value of 1.

I am trying to determine how to chart this in a way where I would have only **TWO** slices, "Apples" and "Oranges", with each showing a value of 2.

Is there a solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there's any way you could achieve that in a pie chart with your current data source format. Ideally you'd have one row per answer as I'm sure you already know.

You could perhaps create a bar chart by creating two metrics using regexp_match:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN regexp_match(fruitdimension, 'Oranges') then 1 else 0 END)

SUM(CASE WHEN regexp_match(fruitdimension, 'Apples') then 1 else 0 END)
```